# Athena "Given Correlated subquery is not supported"

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

This query works outside of Athena (in DB2). For the most part it's working in Athena when I comment out the "having max(column1) > 3" line. But, the error that Athena returns when I "RUN" is saying SYNTAX_ERROR: line 23:9: Given correlated subquery is not supported. The line corresponds with "and not exists":

```
select
*
from t1
where
product = 'SHIRT'
and t1.year = '2022' and t1.month = '07' and t1.day ='31'
and not exists
(
select max(column1) from a2
        where trim(a2.id) = trim(t1.id) --these are strings with trailing spaces, hence the trim here
        having max(column1) > 3
        )
limit 10
```

Athena seems to be fine with the having clause because I wrote a statement as such and it worked: `select max(column1)  from a2  having max(column1) > 3`

It just seems to throw something off when I have it in the "and not exists"? Not sure if that's the reason...

It's not the "and not exists" statement because I have used that previously and it worked.

I cannot figure out what Athena is fussing about. Looking for additional ideas or how I can better debug the issue?

Comment: Error is quite self-explanatory - Athena "is fussing about" about correlated subquery i.e. the subquery in the parenthesis after last `and` - reference to the `t1` makes it correlated and correlated subquery in Presto is limited.

Comment: Try changing it to `(<subquery>) <= 3` and add `coalesce(max(column1), 0)`

Comment: Or `select 1 from ... and column1 > 3` would work too wouldn't it? You don't actually need to aggregate in the subquery.

Comment: So it boils down to not being able to use “having” clause in a subquery in Athena?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a convoluted way of getting there, but I think this is along the lines of what you're looking for. Since the query engine can't handle certain correlated sub-queries (likely for performance reasons), so you need to refactor your code to not include that statement.

You need access to the id from both tables to perform your filter so you need to join the tables. I think this series of table expressions should point you in the right direction. Technically you could also get away with doing everything in a sub-query but instead of trying to access t1 from inside the sub-query, simply join to it, and then instead of the exists clause join the sub-query to the main query and use an additional where clause to drop to rows you are trying to exclude.

```
with cte1 as (
    select *
    from t1
    where product = 'SHIRT'
        and t1.year = '2022'
        and t1.month = '07'
        and t1.day ='31' 
),
cte2 as (
    select
        a2.id,
        max(column1) as abc
    from a2
    inner join cte1
        on trim(cte1.id) = trim(a2.id)
    group by a2.id
)
select cte1.*
from cte1
left join cte2
    on cte2.abc > 3
    and cte2.id = cte1.id
where cte2.id is null
```

or

```
select t1.*
from t1
left join (
    select
        a2.id
        max(column1) as abc
    from a2
    inner join t1
        on a2.id =t1.id
    ) c
    on c.id = t1.id
where product = 'SHIRT'
    and t1.year = '2022'
    and t1.month = '07'
    and t1.day ='31' 
    and c.abc < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

here, the problemn was caused for LIMIT clause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34921402)